# Creating webtest extraction rule for mvc sites querystring

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webtest, web-testing

Can anyone tell me how to create an extraction rule that will allow me to pull an ID from an MVC querystring?

Scenario:

```
User hits site, and clicks "Add new"

Request: www.site.com/item/create
Response: www.site.com/item/view/2143
```

The site will instantly create a new item and redirect them to the viewitem page. The id i would like to extract lives within the response after item/view/####

Current recorded code for webtest:

```
var request4 = new WebTestRequest((Context["WebServerAddress"] + "/Item/Create"));
request4.Method = "POST";
var request4Body = new FormPostHttpBody();
request4.Body = request4Body;
yield return request4;
request4 = null;

//server redirect response happens now

var request5 = 
  new WebTestRequest((Context["WebServerAddress"] + "/Item/Edit/?needIdForHere"));
yield return request5;
request5 = null;
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Kohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may get more mileage setting the value from the `WebTestContext.LastResponse.ResponseUri` as an extraction rule is designed for iterating over the response body.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to use this. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Ahh i got it. The webtest has a context so : var response1 = this.Context.LastResponse.ResponseUri; gives me the string i need.